# Installing Tableau in Ubuntu

Tags: 20.04, upgrade, software-installation, playonlinux, startup-applications

I have been trying to install Tableau Public in Ubuntu 20.04.

1. I installed Wine following the steps as mentioned in https://wiki.winehq.org/Ubuntu.
2. I installed Play on Linux with `sudo apt install playonlinux`.
3. I downloaded the .exe file of Tableau Public from https://public.tableau.com/en-us/s/download.
4. I installed Tableau in Play on Linux after configuring it with Wine.

Even an icon appeared in Ubuntu desktop as Tableau Public 2020.4.lnk, which is an **Application**, according to its **Properties**.
But, whenever I try to open the file, it fails to open.